# How do I update the model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a jQuery [auto complete plugin](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/).

When a user clicks on a suggestion it updates the text box that the plugin is assigned to. Given that the text box has an ng-model directive assigned to it, how do I get angular to run the $parsers so that I can validate the new value?

(There's an onSelect event raised by the plugin)

Comment: Show us teh codez. Hard to help with just words.

Comment: Have a look at the demos on the website. That's all my code does except that the text box has an ng-model attribute on it.

Comment: Sorry bro, not going to go you your site and dig through the code, if you posted something concise in the question though...

Comment: Some code in a plugin updates a text box. Then an event is raised that looks like this... "onSelect: function (suggestion) {};" What goes inside the "{}" that makes Angular update the model?

Comment: By the way, its not my website and I didn't expect you to dig into any code. Its just a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at angular's custom validation functions.  There are examples in the [forms section](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#customvalidation) of the developer guide.

Answer (score 0):

I needed my code in a directive and I needed to update the $viewModel inside of a call to $apply:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', ['storeService', function(storeService) {

    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $model) {

            var options = {
                serviceUrl: '/api/stores',
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $model.$setViewValue(suggestion);
                    });
                }
            };

            $element.autocomplete(options);

        }
    };

}]);
```